`remember picture` doesn't work properly
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
                every node/.style={align=center},
                ent/.style={text width=2.5cm},
            ]
            \node[ent,](prover){\Large\textbf{Prover}};
            \node[ent,right=2cm of prover](verifier){\Large\textbf{Verifier}};
            \node[below=.5cm of verifier](CRP){
                \begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
                    \hline
                    Challenge                                                                         & Response                                                                          \\\hline
                    \(c_1\)                                                                           & \(r_1\)                                                                           \\\hline
                    \tikz[baseline=(ASS.base),remember picture]{\node[fill=magenta!30](ASS){\(c_2\)}} & \tikz[baseline=(BSS.base),remember picture]{\node[fill=magenta!30](BSS){\(r_2\)}} \\\hline
                    \(\vdots\)                                                                        & \(\vdots\)                                                                        \\\hline
                    \(c_n\)                                                                           & \(r_n\)                                                                           \\\hline
                \end{tabular}
            };
            \node[ent]at(CRP-|prover)(PUF){\(r_2'=\mathtt{PUF}({c_2})\)};
            \draw[overlay, -latex](ASS)--(PUF);
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \end{document}



Never nest tikz pictures

Use a tikz matrix instead of a table in a node. This way you can directly reference the cell.

Please add a short, but compilable test file which allows us to reproduce the problem. It should include a class, the necessary packages and a document environment.

Why you need remember picture option? I what result you expected? Do you compile your example at least twice?

Thank you for your various advice.

Are you after for something like this:

With use just common option remember picture and tblr of tabularray package for table:
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                positioning}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 3mm and 17mm,
   ent/.style = {text width=22mm, align=center, font=\Large\bfseries},
   box/.style = {fill=magenta!30},
remember picture, 
            ]
            \node[ent]                  (prover)    {Prover};
            \node[ent,right=of prover]  (verifier)  {Verifier};
            \node[below=of verifier]   {
                \begin{tblr}{hlines, vlines,
                             colspec= {Q[c, m] Q[c, m]}
                             }
                    Challenge   &   Response    \\ 
                    \(c_1\)     &   \(r_1\)     \\ 
                    \tikz[baseline=(ASS.base)]  {\node[box] (ASS)   {\(c_2\)};} 
                                &   \tikz[baseline=(ASS.base)]  {\node[box] (BSS)   {\(r_2\)};} 
                                                \\ 
                    \(\vdots\)  &   \(\vdots\)  \\ 
                    \(c_n\)     &   \(r_n\)     \\ 
                \end{tblr}
                                            };
            \node   at (ASS -| prover)(PUF) {\(r_2'=\mathtt{PUF}({c_2})\)};
            \draw[-Stealth]   (PUF) -- (ASS);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

As you can see, I took a liberty and a wee bit change your styles definitions and their use.
Edit:
Above solution works fine more or less by accident. Better approach is to use \subnode of tikzmark library as follows:
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                backgrounds,    % new
                fit,            % new
                positioning,
                tikzmark}       % new
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 3mm and 17mm,
   ent/.style = {text width=22mm, align=center, font=\Large\bfseries},
%
    sn/.style = {fill=magenta!30,
                 inner xsep=-2pt, inner ysep=0pt,
                 fit=(#1), node contents={}},
remember picture,
                        ]
\node[ent]                  (prover)    {Prover};
\node[ent,right=of prover]  (verifier)  {Verifier};
\node[below=of verifier]   {%
    \begin{tblr}{hlines, vlines,
                 colspec= {Q[c, m] Q[c, m]},
                 row{3} = {belowsep=4pt}
                 }
        Challenge   &   Response    \\
        \(c_1\)     &   \(r_1\)     \\
        \subnode{ASS}{\(c_2\)}
                    &   \subnode{BSS}{\(r_2\)}
                                    \\
        \(\vdots\)  &   \(\vdots\)  \\
        \(c_n\)     &   \(r_n\)     \\
    \end{tblr}
                            };
\node   at (ASS -| prover)(PUF) {\(r_2'=\mathtt{PUF}({c_2})\)};
\scoped[on background layer]
{
    \node (a) [sn=ASS];
    \node (b) [sn=BSS];
}
\node   at (ASS -| prover)(PUF) {\(r_2'=\mathtt{PUF}({c_2})\)};
\draw[-Stealth]   (PUF) -- (ASS);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

result is the same as before.

While you can't nest tikzpictures, you can put them into saveboxes.  (I believe tabulararray does this automatically.)
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\newsavebox{\tempbox}
\begin{document}
\savebox{\tempbox}{\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
                    \hline
                    Challenge                                                                         & Response                                                                          \\\hline
                    \(c_1\)                                                                           & \(r_1\)                                                                           \\\hline
                    \tikz[baseline=(ASS.base),remember picture]{\node[fill=magenta!30](ASS){\(c_2\)}} & \tikz[baseline=(BSS.base),remember picture]{\node[fill=magenta!30](BSS){\(r_2\)}} \\\hline
                    \(\vdots\)                                                                        & \(\vdots\)                                                                        \\\hline
                    \(c_n\)                                                                           & \(r_n\)                                                                           \\\hline
                \end{tabular}}%
\noindent\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,
                every node/.style={align=center},
                ent/.style={text width=2.5cm},
            ]
            \node[ent,](prover){\Large\textbf{Prover}};
            \node[ent,right=2cm of prover](verifier){\Large\textbf{Verifier}};
            \node[below=.5cm of verifier](CRP){\usebox\tempbox};
            \node[ent]at(ASS-|prover)(PUF){\(r_2'=\mathtt{PUF}({c_2})\)};
            \draw[overlay, -latex](ASS)--(PUF);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


This is one way of fleshing out a suggestion made in the comments to use a matrix, which uses the extended syntax supported by the matrix library. This avoids both nesting tikzpictures and any need for remember picture.
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \matrix (m) [matrix of math nodes,nodes={text width=20mm,align=center,anchor=base}]
  {
    \textbf{Prover} &[10mm] \\[5mm]
                     &  \text{Challenge}  & \text{Response} \\
                     & c_1  & r_1 \\
    r_2'=\mathtt{PUF}({c_2}) &|[fill=magenta!20]| c_2  &|[fill=magenta!20]| r_2 \\
                     & \vdots & \vdots  \\
                     & c_n  & r_n   \\
  };
  \foreach \i in {north,west,south,east}
  \foreach \j/\k in {2/a,3/b}
  \coordinate (\k\i) at (m-2-\j.\i);
  \foreach \i in {2,...,6}
  {
    \draw (m-\i-2.north -| awest) coordinate (d) -- (d -| beast);
  }
  \foreach \i in {2,3} \draw (m-2-\i.north east) coordinate (e) -- (m-6-\i.south -| e);
  \draw (m-2-2.north west) -- (m-6-2.south -| awest) (awest |- m-6-2.south) -- (beast |- m-6-2.south);
  \node [anchor=base,font=\bfseries] at (aeast |- m-1-1.base) {Verifier} ;
  \draw [-Stealth] (m-4-1.east) coordinate (f) -- (m-4-2.west |- f);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


